# Cross validation in classifying text documents using scikit-learn

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation

Do you first do cross validation followed by feature extraction or the other way while classifying text documents using scikit-learn?

Here is my pipeline:

```
union = FeatureUnion(
transformer_list = [
 ('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer()),
 ('featureEx', FeatureExtractor()),
 ('spell_chker', Spellingchecker()),
 ], n_jobs = -1)
```

I am doing it in the following way, but I wonder if I should extract the features first and do the cross validation. In this example `X` is list of documents and `y` is label.

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size= 0.2)

X_train = union.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = union.transform(X_test)

ch2 = SelectKBest(f_classif, k = 7000)
X_train = ch2.fit_transform(X_train, y_train)
X_test  = ch2.transform(X_test)

clf = SVC(C=1, gamma=0.001, kernel = 'linear', probability=True).fit(
X_train , y_train)

print("classification report:")
y_true, y_pred = y_test, clf.predict(X_test)
print(classification_report(y_true, y_pred))
print()
```

Answer (score 1):

Doing the feature selection and then cross validating on those features is sometimes common on text data, but it is less desirable. This can lead to over-fitting and the cross-validation procedure may over-estimate your true accuracy.

When you do the feature selection first, that feauter selection process got to look at *all* the data. The point of cross validation is to hide 1 fold from the others. By doing the FS first, you leak some of that data knowledge to the other folds.

Comment: The question is feature extraction vs. cross validation, not feature selection vs. cross validation

Comment: The same still applies. The Term Frequency and Inverse Document Frequency (the TF and IDF in Tfidf vectorizer) contain formation from all documents. I just used a different term.